# Spark Shell command failing on local

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-shell

I am trying to run spark-shell command locally and I am getting below error

> java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service
> 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)!
> Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the
> service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for
> SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.

I am using my companies MAC and I don't have admin access to run sudo command to change host address to 127.0.0.1

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the spark shell in localhost , try to stop spark then restart it again, If you are running the spark-shell from your machine it can be that you are using a terminal of a distant server . It is possible too that the ports which spark is trying to bind are already in use

Comment: I am running spark on local machine however since I am connected to the internet the IP address changes for local machine hence I am getting this error. But when I disconnect it works fine. Not sure how to tackle this issue. if I have admin right when I enter command $ sudo hostname -s 127.0.0.1 then it works.

Comment: So if I understood you well you don't have the right to use 'sudo hostname -s 127.0.0.1' as you are not the admin , well what I advise you is that you simply ask your company to deliver you the password or to set you as an admin to your mac.